# Convert hex to decimal in MS SQL Not Working

Tags: sql

Convert hex to decimal in MS SQL Not Working:
MS Query:

declare @hex varchar(316)
 SET @hex = '143307ac2b0a93795113'
 SELECT CONVERT(int,CONVERT (binary(1000),@hex,1))

Error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
>   Error converting data type varchar to varbinary.

Comment: It should be `0x00f81ec1bc94fb00a9` if you are using convert, you are missing the `0x`part. But please post what you have tried and what error you got

Comment: Regardless of what you're doing with the hexstring,`143307ac2b0a93795113` isn't going to fit into an `INT`, and a conversion will just lop off everything but the last 4 bytes (not the first 4 bytes!). In other words, even if your code actually worked you'd get the equivalent of `SELECT CONVERT(INT, 0x93795113)`. Is that what you want or are you trying to achieve something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @hex VARCHAR(316);
SET @hex = '143307ac2b0a93795113';

SELECT CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX('0x', @hex) > 0 THEN --if 0x presents
               CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @hex, 1))
           ELSE -- if 0x does not present
               CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @hex, 2))
       END;
```

Comment: [Don't declare `VAR` types without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) (the post is about `VARCHAR`, but it applies equally to `VARBINARY`). In this context, `VARBINARY` means `VARBINARY(30)`, not "whatever is large enough to hold the result". A `VARCHAR(316)` would need a `VARBINARY(158)` in the worst case.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Answer updated. Thank you for the comment

Comment: Could you provide solutions for hex to decimal in MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

> If the style is set to 1, the must have 0x as the first two
>   characters. If the expression contains an odd number of characters, or
>   if any of the characters is invalid, an error is raised.
>
> Binary styles The characters 0x will be added to the left of the
>   converted result for style 1.